# Install Laravel on dedicated server's subfolder

Tags: laravel

So I am having an issue with pushing a Laravel app to production on a dedicated server's subfolder.

Server is run on `Apache`.

Url I want to push my app would be `subdomain.domain.com/project`

The structure of my dedicated server is

```
.cpanel
...
-laravel
  -app
  -vendor
  -...
-public_ftp
-public_html
  -folder
     -contents of laravels public directory
-ssl
```

I know that in order not to expose my hidden files I am required to install it in a root directory, but this is not an option because I will be having multiple projects running under `subdomain.domain.com/project-1`, `subdomain.domain.com/project-2` and etc... and all will have a separate laravel installation.

I need a hand in order to achieve that, can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Your subdomain is already configured in Apache?

Comment: yes, Apache configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do it myself, the problem was when i was creating a symlink, so instead i just moved contents of my public directory to public_html/project-1/ and changed index.php path to `/../../laravel/`

The thing was that I have done it originally but I didnt expect that permissions for storage need to be manually set, that solved my issue and laravel works.

ALWAYS CHECK ERROR LOGS :)

Answer (score 0):

You can place your separate folders in your subdomain with no problem.
The important thing is that you need to point the browser to public/ folder under your laravel projects.

You can create a .htaccess file with the command below in root folder of each project and perform a redirect.

Place the following command in your .htaccess file:
RedirectMatch ^/$ /public/

Comment: Not eactly what I wanted, as I said, I don't want to expose my laravel files to public, So the installation I did was to create a folder in a root directory, copy all vendor,bootstrap and etc, and put all of my contents of public directory in a folder under public_html. This is where I am stuck now.

Comment: This article can help you in this case: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/laravel-51-change-name-and-location-of-public-folder.

Comment: One of the answers is to create a symlink. In this case, you maintain your public/ folder inside your laravel project and create a symlink to this folder under public_html/. Hope this can help!

Comment: Thats exactly what I have done, but the problem is that my .htaccess file does not redirect to /public when i type in full url like so `subdomain.domain.com` it just outputs me the content of the directory with a public folder as symlink